# QGIS area calculation

Tags: qgis, area

When I calculate an area with area measure in QGis, it gives as a result values of area 44% more area than in reality, any idea why?

Comment: Does the projection of the vector layer matches the projection of the QGIS project (Located in the lower left)?

Comment: What is your projection? For example EPSG:3857 makes heavy distortion towards the poles.